# using python to ssh fully into server

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I've been trying to automate ssh'ing into my server however cannot find a way to fully automate the process. To be specific, getting around this input has been the struggle: root@example's password:

My code:

```
import subprocess
import time

server_ip = 'server'
pwd = b'password'


p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'root@{}'.format(server_ip)],
                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

if p == "root@example's password: ":
    p.communicate(input= "{}".format(pwd))
else:
    time.sleep(2)
    if p == "root@example's password: ":
        p.communicate(input= "{}".format(pwd))
    else:
        pass
```

What it returns:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
root@example's password: 
user@computer ~ % Permission denied, please try again.
root@example's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@example's password: 
root@example: Permission denied (publickey,password).
I know my code is very scuffed but it is the furthest I've got to getting in and submitting the password entry request.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you can use `paramiko` to remotely execute command with python over ssh connection. would that help?

Comment: Also worth to checkout http://www.fabfile.org/

Answer (score 0):

`if p == "root@example's password: ":` can never be true; `p` is a `subprocess.Popen` object, not a string.

You can get a string by reading from the object's standard output, but of course, `ssh` prints the prompt message on the `tty`, so you can't easily capture it from Python.

Notice also that without an `encoding` keyword argument or `text=True`, you can't send or receive strings; the output you receive will be a `b'...'` byte string which cannot be compared to a regular string.

... But even if you managed to sort out these problems, taking it from there to a fully working interactive SSH session is still quite some distance to go. I would definitely recommend that you try `pexpect` or Paramiko instead of rolling your own, especially if you are new to Python.

Tangentially, `else: pass` is completely unnecessary; there is no reason to add an `else:` block in the first place if you don't have anything useful to put in it.
And
As `"{}".format(pwd)` is a really hairy way to write what can be more easily expressed as `pwd`, or `str(pwd)` if it's not already a string.